How can we know the $f$-invariant measures?
I was reading the answer to the following question here What are the $f$- invariant measures?:
Let $X$ be the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2.$ Let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix with real entries, determinant 1, and which does not have finite order. Define
$f: X \to X$ by $$\frac{A(v)}{|A(v)|}.$$ First let $$\begin{matrix}
a & 0 \\
0 & 1/a
\end{matrix}$$ for $a > 0.$
1- What are the fixed points of $f$ when $f$ is defined using this matrix A?
2- What are the $f$- invariant measures?
My questions are:
Apparantly the author of the answer provided an answer to question one but he did not provide any answer to question two, so I am repeating the question of the OP there,  How can we know the $f$-invariant measures?  any hints or ideas will be greatly appreciated!

I assume that we are talking about invariant probability measures.
You can show easily (say by induction) that
$$
f^n(v)=\frac{A^nv}{|A^nv|}
$$
for each $n\in\mathbb N$. Writing $v=(x,y)$ we have
$$
A^nv=\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 \\
0 & 1/a
\end{pmatrix}^nv=(a^nx,y/a^n)
$$
and so really all that matters are the directions of this vector (since $|A^nv|$ only gives a normalization).
$\bullet$ First assume that $a=1$. Then $f$ is the identity map, and so all points are fixed points, and of course all measures on the circle are invariant.
$\bullet$ Now let's assume that $a>1$ (you can consider similarly the case $a<1$).
Then the intersections of $X$ with the axes are fixed points (since $a^n\ne 1/a^n$ no other point is fixed by $f$). For other points, $f^n(v)$ converges to $(1,0)$ because $a^n\to+\infty$ when $n\to+\infty$. This means that in this case there are only invariant measures supported on the fixed points. That is, the family of (probability) invariant measures is
$$
\mu=c_1\delta_{(1,0)}+c_2\delta_{(-1,0)}+c_3\delta_{(0,1)}+c_4\delta_{(0,-1)}
$$
for any constants $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4\ge0$ with $c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4=1$. Here $\delta_p$ is the $\delta$ measure supported at the point $p$.
The same holds when $a<1$ although in this case if $v$ is not a fixed point, then $f^n(v)$ converges instead to $(0,1)$ because $a^n\to0$ when $n\to+\infty$.

why you are adding $c_2$ three times in your equation of $\mu$?

I corrected the typo with the $c_2$. We found that the measure takes values only on the fixed points (because all orbits other than the fixed points converge to a fixed point). This is the same as saying that its support contains at most the four fixed points.

And why $c_1+c_2+c_3+c_4=1$? So that you have a probability measure. If you want an arbitrary measure just drop this requirement.

why we need $f^n$ and not just $f^{-1}$ in the definition of f invariant?

The map is invertible.

You should clarify from the beginning that you described invariant probability measures (this is hidden in the middle of the answer) and the question is imprecise in this regard. In fact, there are other invariant infinite measures (too many to describe). Furthermore, the proof works even if you assume that the probability measure is only finitely additive. Lastly, what's important here is not pointwise convergence, but uniform convergence on compacts (outside of the repelling fixed point).  One realizes this by analyzing why "it means" actually holds.

@MoisheKohan Fixed.
